# Scope and the 'self' keyword

Tags: ruby, scope, self

I have the following code:

```
def self.ftoc(temp_in_fahrenheit)
     (temp_in_fahrenheit - 32) * 5.0/9.0
end

def self.ctof(temp_in_celcius)
     (temp_in_celcius * 9.0/5.0) + 32
end

def calculate_temperatures
    @f = Temperature.ctof(@c) if (@f == nil && @c != nil)
    @c = Temperature.ftoc(@f) if (@c == nil && @f != nil)
end
```

This works fine. However, if I changed the code to

```
def calculate_temperatures
    @f = self.ctof(@c) if (@f == nil && @c != nil)
    @c = self.ftoc(@f) if (@c == nil && @f != nil)
end
```

I get an error of

```
undefined method 'ftoc' for #<Temperature:0x000000025486a0 @f=50>
```

I would have thought that 'self', as an instance of class Temperature, would be able to use the ctof/ftoc methods, but that isn't the case. Can somebody help me understand what I'm missing?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside method `self` is *an instance* of `Temperature`. Inside `class` it is an instance of `Class`, having a name `Temperature`.

Try this:

```
class Temperature
  puts "Inside class: self is #{self}, Temperature is #{Temperature}"

  def meth
    puts "Inside method: self is #{self}, Temperature is #{Temperature}"
  end
end

Temperature.new.meth
```

That said, inside `class`, those are equivalent:

```
class Temperature
  def self.meth ; end
  def Temperature.meth ; end
end
```

But inside `method`, `self` becomes in instance variable, while the constant `Temperature`, instance of `Class`, still refers to what you expected.

To refer it’s class from inside instance method, one might use `self.class`. That said, inside instance method, those are equivalent:

```
class Temperature
  def meth
    Temperature.ctof(...)
    self.class.ctof(...)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going with this as the answer because my confusion stemmed from the fact that 'self' changes depending on where it's being used, and this helped me understand that point.

Answer (score 1):

`ftoc` and `ctof` are class methods, because you specified the `self` keyword in the declaration.
In an other hand, `calculate_temperatures` is an instance method.

what you should do in order to access class methods in instance methods is using `self.class` :

```
def calculate_temperatures
    @f = self.class.ctof(@c) if (@f == nil && @c != nil)
    @c = self.class.ftoc(@f) if (@c == nil && @f != nil)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any reason that self.class.ctof is better/preferred than Temperature.ctof or Temperature::ctof?

Comment: Yes, using `self.class` will ease the use of polymorphism. Plus, it is easier to read the code and understand that the class method you call is defined on the same class hierarchy than the instance method caller.

Comment: There is no notion of “better” and “worse.” Whether you want `Temperature.ctof` to be called, you should call it that way. On the other hand, if you want to provide an ability for your class users to _override_ this method, you should call `self.class.ctof`. In this particular case it’s evident, that `Temperature.ctof` is a right choice, while `self.class.ctof` is vulnerable to accidental overwriting.